# Why leetcode is producing different result than pycharm and jupyter-notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It sounds strange but I copied pasted and used the same input for the method, I get the correct result on my machine but leetcode is producing different result for the same code. this is the code on leetcode for Q-377:

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int,memo={}) -> int:
       
        if target in memo:
            return memo[target]
        
        if target==0:
            return 1
        if target<0:
            return 0 
        count=0
        for num in nums: 
            remainder=target-num
            count+=self.combinationSum4(nums,remainder)
        
        memo[target]=count
        return count
```

this is the result I am getting for nums=[9] target=3

[image]

this is the result on jupyter and pycharm. same code. I copied from leetcode:

[image]

this pycahrm[image]

I also tried this solution got same issue:

[image]

Comment: `memo={}`,  I think it is the cause.

Comment: the [leetcode] tag has been [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399117/we-need-to-de-leet-leetcode) before and should not be recreated.

Comment: You might want to read: [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question in Leetcode doesn't have the argument `memo = {}`. This is from LC code.

> `def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:`

Since you are changing the functions arguments, it works for you **only** in PyCharm or Jupyter. But Leetcode will only pass the required arguments i.e `nums` and `target` and **not** `memo = {}`. **You need to write your code the LC's way.**

If you intend to change the arguments of function. You can write a separate functions with the arguments you need and call it from within `combinationSum4()` function.

Here is the Code:

```
class Solution:
    def solve(self, nums, target, memo):
            if target in memo:
                return memo[target]

            if target==0:
                return 1
            if target<0:
                return 0 
            count=0
            for num in nums: 
                remainder=target-num
                count += self.solve(nums,remainder,memo)

            memo[target]=count
            return count
    
    def combinationSum4(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        # Calling the function
        return self.solve(nums, target, {})
```

Comment: Ram, your code has same issue. I run the code with nums=[9] and target=3. It gives me 0 on my machine but  4 on leetcode

Comment: I just ran this code on LC, I am getting a 0 (correct answer). [This](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/) is the problem. right ?

Comment: i am going to update the the question with the image of your solution. I also tried on firefox and got same result

Comment: I added the result of your solution

Comment: I just **ran** the code and it gave a 0 (status was Accepted). But when I **submit**, it's giving a 4 as answer (status Wrong Answer). Strange!

Comment: I am glad you saw it. I thought  i was losing my mind :)

Comment: I got it! What is wrong is, we are using a default value for ```memo = {}```. That's the culprit. I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: Thank you. this question was the first question I solved on  my own but leetcode gave me headache.